# linux sort, select last line, pipe to new file

Tags: linux, sorting, csv, grep

I have a series of multiple files.  I would like to sort these files, select the bottom line from each, and pipe those lines into a new single file.

My files look like this:

```
1,  100,  2.5
2,  100,  3.3
3,  100,  5.1
4,  100,  1.2
```

These files are all named 51_Sur_extracted_data.csv

The files are housed in parent directories as follows:

Track_0001/output_dfsu/51_Sur_extracted_data.csv
Track_0002/output_dfsu/51_Sur_extracted_data.csv

So I would like to sort all of the csv files on the 3rd column, extract the bottom line, and place it into a new summary file.  Basically the goal is produce a file that has the maximum values from column three across all of the parent directories.  Ideally, I would also like to add a column in the output file that contains the name of the parent directory (Track_0002).

I have the sort figured out, but the rest is proving a bit troublesome for me.  For instance, can I sort all of the csv files at the same time and write the output to new files (example 51_Sur_extracted_data_sort.csv)?  Then I can grep the last line and pipe it to a new file?

```
sort -t"," -k3,3g filename
```

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 3):

IF you want the last line of any given command, use `tail`.

So for you, you would do this:

```
sort -t"," -k3,3g filename | tail -n1 > newfilename
```

Comment: can I do this across multiple files?  I suppose I can just build a loop.

Comment: Elaborate on "do this across multiple files".  You can specify multiple inputs to `sort`, but it will all be one output stream that gets sent to `tail` and then redirected to `newfilename`.

Comment: @AndyLester The question has a lot of detail about that already

Comment: No, there is no way to say "sort all these files into all these other files".  You'll need a loop.

Comment: I tried, sort -t"," -k3,3g Track_*/output_dfsu/51_$.csv | tail -n1 > 51_sur_extracted_data_sort.csv, and it returned only one line.

Comment: That's exactly what I said would happen in my comment 11 minutes before yours.  "You can specify multiple inputs to sort, but it will all be one output stream that gets sent to tail and then redirected to newfilename."

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
for a in */*/*.csv
do 
    dname="$(basename "$(dirname "$a")")"
    echo -e "$dname\t$(sort -t"," -k3,3g "$a" | tail -n 1)"
done
```

On my test files it returned:

```
output_abcd 3,  100,  9.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 1,  100,  7.5
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 2,  100,  42.3
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.2
output_abcd 3,  100,  5.1
output_bcde 3,  100,  5.1
output_cdef 3,  100,  5.1
```

Yeah, my input data is a bit boring. Of course you can sort the end result *again*, but I'll leave that to your imagination (you already had that step) :)

Comment: See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c715776b9e7e8ca)** complete with my demo data in 27 dirs/files